# How to add new Properties to an existing class at runtime independent of existing members with read-write capability in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtime, properties, creation

I need to make a property for each column in a database table but we do not know the number of columns before hand.
It is mainly for reuseability.

Comment: One of your keywords might be a valid solution (`dynamic`), but you probably need to specify what you want more clearly.  I'm not sure what adding new properties at runtime will get you...

Comment: As i do not know the number of properties i need to create or their names i need them to be created at runtime according to the database table columns. we do not know before hand which database table it will be associated with.

Comment: So there will never be any code written in your application which knows the name of the property - since these names are not known until runtime?  In which case what purpose does the property serve?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) rather

Comment: I am restricted from using a Dictionary or a Hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that's usable (or possible), because properties are more useful at design-time, so you can easily find and use them.
If you were able to create them at runtime, how do you expect the coder to know a property will exist?  The compiler won't even see the name of the property.
Even if you use reflection at that point, you still need to specify the name of the property textually.

Hence, using a `DataTable` to represent the corresponding database table is one way to give you that feeling of run-time dynamics.
Another way is to use the key-value pair approach with `Dictionary` for each row, and store them all in a `HashSet` or a `List`, depending on the rest of your solution, to represent a table.

Comment: the coder does not need to know the names of the properties before hand. The name of the property required will be given to us by the user of the application. he will already know the database table and the columns and their names. I am restricted from using a datatable or a hashtable or a hashset or a dictionary or a list. I need to create properties.

Comment: @Sharpsaber -- That's not what a property is made for, which is why the answer is "you cannot create properties on the fly".